# CORS with React JS and ASP Web API

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an application using React JS and ASP Web API where I am facing a problem 
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:53248/api/home/saveData. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

My react component code is

```
submitData(event) {
    fetch("http://localhost:53248/api/home/saveData", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            // userName: this.state.userName,
            // password: this.state.password,
            email: this.state.email
        })
    }).then((Response) => Response.json())
        .then((findresponse) => {
            if (findresponse.result == 'authenticated')
                alert("1");
            else
                alert("2");
    })
}
```

Any help for this issue.

Comment: Start by adding cors support in your ASP Web API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

Comment: Yes it is working. Thank you